# SQL Consecutive value meet certain threshold

Tags: sql

I have a table like below.

Table A

```
|id |value1|
 --  ------
|123|    89|
|123|     8|
|123|    90|
|123|    6 |
|123|   100|
|123|    45| 
|123|    46|
|123|    77|
|123|     1|
|123|    55|
|123|     8|
|123|    65|
```

The goal is to find consecutive rows which are <= 60

Desired results:

```
|id |  value1|
 --- --------
|123|      45|
|123|      46|
|123|       1|
|123|      55|
|123|       8|
```

I have tried lead and lag function like other solution provided with no luck. Hope anyone may help here!

Comment: I think you can just use `where`

Comment: Sorry, missed some data in the table. There will be cases where non-consecutive < 60 value presents.

Comment: Your table is lacking one or more columns which provides the _ordering_ which your data above is suggesting.  Without this column(s), your question cannot be answered.

Comment: Please tag the DB type you're using.

Comment: *consecutive* implies a *sequence* which your sample data does not have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you try this? I've wrote it in BigQuery but you can understand the logic in it.

```sql
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 123 AS id, [89, 8, 90, 6, 100, 45, 46, 77, 1, 55, 8, 65] values
),
consecutives AS (
  SELECT id, value,
         IF (value <= 60 AND (
             LEAD(value) OVER (ORDER BY idx) <= 60 OR
             LAG(value) OVER (ORDER BY idx) <= 60 ), 1, 0
         ) AS is_consecutive,
    FROM data, UNNEST(values) value WITH OFFSET idx
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(is_consecutive) FROM consecutives WHERE is_consecutive = 1;

Result:
+-----+-------+
| id  | value |
+-----+-------+
| 123 |    45 |
| 123 |    46 |
| 123 |     1 |
| 123 |    55 |
| 123 |     8 |
+-----+-------+
```

As @tim-biegeleisen metioned, the table should have `ordering` column, so I've added it with name `idx`.